# Syntastic not working with MiniBufExplorer vim plugin

Tags: vim, syntastic, minibufexplorer

First off I'm a windows user using VIM and vundle to manage my plugins.

I have the Syntastic vim plugin (https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) and it works great highlighting any syntax errors for the first javascript file I open and save.

I also have the minibufexplorer plugin (https://github.com/sontek/minibufexpl.vim). Once I open a second file the MiniBufExplorer window appears allowing me to navigate between previously opened files via :b1, :b2, etc.  I've noticed when this happens Syntastic stops working.

If I remove the minibufexplorer plugin then Syntastic always works.  I'd really like to get both working together, does anyone have a solution for this?  I would gladly use an alternative to minibufexplorer if it works with Syntastic.

Comment: If you do `:e` in the window where the opened file is, will Syntastic work again?

Comment: Just a precision: `:b2` is not provided by a plugin: it's a builtin command.

Comment: @244an no unfortunately not

Comment: @romainl thanks I didn't realize.  Only been using vim for a few months so I'm still a sponge soaking up new info.  Just read up on vim buffers and using :ls is a valid workaround for me. I lose the persistently displayed buffer list but the buffer list is only one command away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm open to alternatives I will be removing the MiniBufExplorer plugin and using the :ls vim command to view the buffer list when desired.  It's not as convenient as using the MiniBufExplorer plugin but I find syntax highlighting more important and am satisfied with this workaround.

Comment: Add this line to your `~/.vimrc`: `nnoremap gb :ls<CR>:b` you can then type the number of the desired buffer followed by `<Enter>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to organize my installed plugins. I have [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) and [minibufexplorer](https://github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim) and they work well together for me.

I have done no configuration at all to any of thees plugins. But to handle bufferswitching in an easy way (also works without minibufexplorer) I use this in my `.vimrc`:

```
map § :bnext^M
map ½ :bprevious^M
```

Its the key just below the Esc-key. It makes it very easy to just hit the § key to cycle through all open buffers.

[Here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen/) is a good place to start your configuration.